# Keep count of read for each month in array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have an array of object as:

```
const sampleArray = [{"read":true,"readDate":2021-01-15T18:21:34.059Z},
                     {"read":true,"readDate":2021-01-15T18:21:34.059Z},
                     {"read":true,"readDate":2021-02-15T18:21:34.059Z},
                     {"read":true,"readDate":2021-04-15T18:21:34.059Z},
                     {"read":true,"readDate":2021-12-15T18:21:34.059Z}]
```

I want to keep count of read for each month and where the month is missing it should give 0.

Expected O/P :

```
 [2,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12] => In jan -2 count, feb - 1 count, april - 1 count, dec - 1 count and rest months there is no read data.
```

For this I tried :

```
let invoiceInfoArray = [];
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();
for (let i = 0; i < sampleArray.length; i++) {
     if (sampleArray[i].readDate.getMonth() + 1 == n) {
           invoiceInfoArray.push(invoiceInfo[i])
      }
}
```

Also I thought as if I check for each condition but this will also not be feasible as it will check for particular month and if not available it will automatically insert 0 for rest which is incorrect,

```
   for (let i = 0; i < sampleArray.length; i++) {
       if (sampleArray[i].readDate.getMonth() + 1 == 1) {
             invoiceInfoArray.push(invoiceInfo[i])
       } else if (sampleArray[i].readDate.getMonth() + 1 != 1) {
             invoiceInfoArray.push(0)
       } else if (sampleArray[i].readDate.getMonth() + 1 == 2) {
             invoiceInfoArray.push(invoiceInfo[i])
       }  else if (sampleArray[i].readDate.getMonth() + 1 != 2) {
             invoiceInfoArray.push(0)
       }
   }
```

I'm unable to form logic on how I can achieve my target such that I want to keep count of read for each month and where the month is missing it should give 0.

Expected O/P :

```
 [2,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1] => In jan -2 count, feb - 1 count, april - 1 count, dec - 1 count and rest months there is no read data.
```

Please let me know if anyone needs any further details. Any guidance will really be helpful.

Comment: How last index result is `12`. It should be 1

Comment: `[
  2, 1, 0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1
]`

Comment: Yes that is correct, I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `array` of `12` length and make the `readDate` as a `Date` object and get the month from `getMonth`.

You can create a new array with `12`elements and prefilled with `0` as

```
const months = Array(12).fill(0);
// or
const months = new Array(12).fill(0);
```

read about [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```js
const sampleArray = [{
    read: true,
    readDate: "2021-01-15T18:21:34.059Z"
  },
  {
    read: true,
    readDate: "2021-01-15T18:21:34.059Z"
  },
  {
    read: true,
    readDate: "2021-02-15T18:21:34.059Z"
  },
  {
    read: true,
    readDate: "2021-04-15T18:21:34.059Z"
  },
  {
    read: true,
    readDate: "2021-12-15T18:21:34.059Z"
  },
];

const months = Array(12).fill(0);
// or
// const months = new Array(12).fill(0);

sampleArray.forEach((obj) => {
  const month = new Date(obj.readDate).getMonth();
  ++months[month];
});

console.log(months);
```

Comment: I couldn't follow const months = Array(12).fill(0); this part...what does it do exactly?

Comment: creating a new array with `Array` function and it fills the array values as `0`

Comment: Ohh so at start only array is filled with 0 and value is getting replaced right?

Comment: Perfect, you can create an array with `12` elements with `constructor` also

Comment: That's really smart. Thank you so much.